# Visual Studio 2010 is not recognizing namespace asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Suddenly, a page I needed to add to is not recognizing the asp tag namespace.

Also, the ToolBox only has HTML and General tabs.

I opened a page I did not try to edit and the Toolbox has all the usual (Standard, Data, AJAX, etc) and the tags are recognized.

Created a brand new WebForm, without a Master Page, and it's the same thing. The Toolbox is missing all the .Net tabs and it will not recognize the asp tags.

Rebooted of course then opened another project. Brand new WebForm and the same thing occurs.

Closed all VS occurances, deleted all files in the ReflectedSchemas folder, still no luck.

Added extra info to the Web.Config:

```
<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Still no luck.

Even tried to create a brand new Web Application Project. Opened the default page and the same thing happens. The toolbox only has the two tabs and it won't recognize the asp tag.

I have been researching this for a while now and I'm at a lose.

The only thing that has changed is two days ago I performed a Windows Update and one update and 6 Hot fixes for VS 2010 were installed but it has been working fine until today.

Any suggestions before I need to take more drastic actions like removing the updates or worse, uninstall VS and re-install it?

Comment: Instead of updating your question with the solution (which has been rolled back by a mod), you should add an answer instead.

Comment: You are right chue +1

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Yesterday I had to reset a few things. Double clicking an aspx page in the solution Explorer was opening the page in a separate browser. So, right click on the page, then choose Open With. I chose HTML Editor and set it as the default. I should have chosen Web form Editor.
I have decided to leave this question here just in case someone else does the same thing as I did....

Live and learn!!!